# How to perform a background task at a given date on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Say I want to perform a background task, like upload some data, at a given date and time after the user has quit my app. So the app is killed, but I still want to run a task later on.

Is that possible? Is there a background mode to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no background mode that awakens your application at a given time. You can use [silent push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html), but in that case you will need to have a backend that send push notifications to your app.

Also you can try using [Background fetch mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh), basically when the system wakes up your app you can check if the current date is the actual date that you need to execute your code.

Comment: It's also important to note that push notifications require internet connection and your application only gets a specified amount of time (~30seconds) to handle the push notification. Also if your app is spending too much resources, the system might decide not to wake the app when a silent push notification arrives.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise the [Background App Refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) capability of iOS to achieve this.

Whilst you cannot specify an exact time to perform your background task, you can set a desired minimum interval to execute the task.

It's worth noting however that a user can disable this capability on both an app and device-wide level, so you should ensure that there is alternative logic to handle this situation.